# Bot Framework: How to create a menu in Node.js SDK?

Tags: node.js, botframework, azure-bot-service, azure-qna-maker

I'm developing a chatbot using Bot Framework and Node.js. My purpose is to guide the user with a Menu. I imagine that the user open the bot and it automatically prompts: " Hi I'm your bot you  what are you looking for? - option1 - option2 "

Once the user clicks on one of the option he can ask me several question connected to that option and I imagine I will attach a specific QnA Maker knowledgebase.

I tried seaching on the web and I looked for the samples posted on Github but are not so helpful. Anyone could help me with a pratical example?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally speaking, you can create several QnAmaker services, and define several  `QnAMakerRecognizer` with different `kb`s in your bot application, then leverage [`recognize()`](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-CognitiveServices/blob/master/Node/src/QnAMakerRecognizer.ts#L85) of `QnAMakerRecognizer` in your bot waterfalls to match the questions, by your own conditions.

For a quick sample:

```
var recognizer1 = new cognitiveservices.QnAMakerRecognizer({
    knowledgeBaseId: <knowledgeBaseId>,
    subscriptionKey: <subscriptionKey>
});
var recognizer2 = new cognitiveservices.QnAMakerRecognizer({
    knowledgeBaseId: <knowledgeBaseId>,
    subscriptionKey: <subscriptionKey>
});
let QNARecognizer;
bot.dialog('/', [(session, args) => {
        var msg = new builder.Message(session)
            .text("Select a choice")
            .suggestedActions(
                builder.SuggestedActions.create(
                    session, [
                        builder.CardAction.imBack(session, "option1", "option1"),
                        builder.CardAction.imBack(session, "option2", "option2"),
                    ]
                )
            );
        builder.Prompts.choice(session, msg, ["option1", "option2"]);
    }, (session, results,next) => {
        console.log(results);
        session.userData.kb = results.response.entity;
        switch (results.response.entity) {
            case 'option1':
            QNARecognizer = recognizer1;
                break;
            case 'option2':
            QNARecognizer = recognizer2;
                break;
            default:
                session.endDialog('not matched');
        }
        builder.Prompts.text(session,'please ask your quesion');
    }, (session, results) => {
        QNARecognizer.recognize(session,(err,result)=>{
            session.send(result.answers[0].answer);
        })
    }
])
```

Comment: That's perfect thanks! Just another question,How I can combine both QnA Recognizer and Luis? I still read something but it was not so helpful, the scenario is the same, I still have 2 Luis services configured on the two QnA maker kb, how will work the integration?

Comment: Yes, you can refer to https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-CognitiveServices/tree/master/Node/samples/Integral for the sample which should solve your requirement.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using a [prompts.Choice](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/nodejs/bot-builder-nodejs-dialog-prompt#promptschoice). This will present the user with buttons for each option - the user can click them or type the response.

So, if you have a [QnAMaker dialog](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-CognitiveServices/blob/master/Node/samples/QnAMaker/README.md) defined ...

```
var recognizer = new cognitiveservices.QnAMakerRecognizer({
    knowledgeBaseId: 'set your kbid here', 
    subscriptionKey: 'set your subscription key here'});

var basicQnAMakerDialog = new cognitiveservices.QnAMakerDialog({
    recognizers: [recognizer],
    defaultMessage: 'No match! Try changing the query terms!',
    qnaThreshold: 0.3
});

bot.dialog('/QnAMakerDialogue', basicQnAMakerDialog);
```

You can switch to this dialog with [replaceDialog](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/nodejs/bot-builder-nodejs-dialog-replace), based on what the user chose ...

```
function (session, results) {
     builder.Prompts.choice(session, "Hi I'm your bot you what are you looking for?", ["Ask a question", "Other cool stuff"], {listStyle: builder.ListStyle.button});
},
function (session, results) {
     if(results.response) {
          switch (results.response.entity) {
                case 'Ask a question':
                   session.replaceDialog('/QnAMakerDialogue');
                case 'Other cool stuff':
                   session.replaceDialog('/CoolStuffDialog');
                default:
                    session.send("Something went horribly wrong");
                    return;
          }
     } 
}
```

If your user has responded that they want to ask a question, you will need to prompt for the question. To do this, I've sometimes used a wrapper dialogue QnAPromptDialogue ...

```
function (session,args,next) {
    //if the user just entered 'ask question' or similar, prompt for the actual question
    var regex  = new RegExp("^ask .*");
    if(regex.test(session.message.text)) {
        builder.Prompts.text(session, "Go ahead, what is your question?");
    } else {
        next();
    }  
},
function (session, results) {
    session.replaceDialog('/QnAMakerDialogue');
}
```

Might not work for everybody, but including in case it's helpful.

Comment: The idea should be create another "var recognizer2" in which I put the data of the second knowledgebase in QnA right?
Looking at the second snippet I tried copy and paste the code inside mine but it generate error so I tried as follow:
'bot.dialog('/', [
    function (session,result) {
        builder.Prompts.choice(session, "Hi I'm your bot you what are you looking for?", ["Ask a question", "Other cool stuff"],{listStyle: builder.ListStyle.button});
    } ...  ' 
But,how my '/QnAMakerDialogue' dialog look like if I want to inglobe QnA kb? I want that when I click I go into a spec kb

Comment: For combining QnA Maker and LUIS, [these samples](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-CognitiveServices/tree/master/Node/samples) work really well, you should be able to check out the repo and run.

Comment: I added an edit above in response to your second question